# Sencha Touch merging ListView back button bar with custom toolbar

Tags: listview, sencha-touch-2

[image]

I have created a custom toolbar which I want to use uniformly across all the views of my app.

PROBLEM: When a ListView item is selected and a detail view loaded, I get the default back button bar and my custom toolbar, as shown above.

How can I merge both bars and have a single bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24836239/sencha-touch-consecutive-listviews-double-back-buttons-issue), I assume you are using an Ext.navigation.View to host your section and vacancy lists.

Instead of creating your own toolbar you could customize the navigationbar of the navigation view. You get access to it by `navigationview.getNavigationBar();` A navigationbar is nothing but an Ext.TitleBar, so you can add components by `navigationbar.add();`

Comment: I have to say THANK YOU. I am very grateful for all your help over the last couple of questions you've helped me with